# What is the time complexity of a HashMap implemented using dynamic array?

Tags: java, data-structures

They say HashMap's put and get operations have a constant time complexity, is it still going to be O(1) if it is implemented with a dynamic array?

ex:

```
 public class HashMap <key, value>{
    private class Entry <k, v>{
        private k key;
        private v value;

        public Entry(k key, v value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList < LinkedList<Entry<key, value>> > = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // the rest of the implementation
    // ...

}
```

Comment: sorry, I changed my question, time complexity of put and get

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - it appears the intended structure is an ArrayList of buckets (which I assume will be indexed by hash value % size) each containing a LinkedList, for hash collisions.  So there's the potential for near-O(1) lookup, depending on the average collisions per bucket.

Comment: Hash tables *are* implemented using dynamic arrays, i.e. they have arrays and they dynamically resize them when needed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing

Comment: @kaya - this could just be a matter of wording. A Java array cannot be resized; you have to allocate a new one and copy.  A Java ArrayList<> can be resized from the point of view of the user; under the covers, the implementation may have a plain array that needs  to be reallocated and copied.  But ArrayList<> **looks** like it is dynamic in a way that an array is not.

Comment: @user16632363 An ArrayList doesn't merely look like a dynamic array - it is, precisely, a dynamic array. The term "dynamic array" means a data structure with an array which is dynamically reallocated as required. Whether that behaviour is implemented in the ArrayList class or the HashMap class must be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap [already uses a dynamic array](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/8a979adeddccf886d6cff144d40dc578ba3a9fe5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L385):

```
/**
 * The table, initialized on first use, and resized as
 * necessary. When allocated, length is always a power of two.
 * (We also tolerate length zero in some operations to allow
 * bootstrapping mechanics that are currently not needed.)
 */
transient Node<K,V>[] table;
```

Using an ArrayList instead of a manually resized array does not increase the time complexity.

Comment: yeah I know but why are they saying its O(1) ?                                                                       Due to the rarity of needing to resize and rehash ?

Comment: Yes.  Ideally, you'll have one element per bucket, on average, and with a close-to-ideal distribution.

Comment: If you resize the array exponentially each time, the number of copies per element is bounded by a constant. For example, if you double it, every element will be copied on average less than 2 times. Since the resize time is constant per insert (amortized), the resizes doesn't add to the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for puts is how often you're going to need to extend the ArrayList.

This is probably little different in overhead to extending a plain array: you have to allocate a new one and rehash.

Note you'll need to know the intended ArrayList size in order to compute the hash index (as hash code % array size), so you should allocate the ArrayList with that capacity initially and then populate with nulls - since the array elements don't exist until added to the list.

Similarly for when you rehash.

You can of course do it wrong: you could compute a size for use in computing the hash index, and then **not** extend the ArrayList accordingly. Then you'd suffer from arbitrary need to extend the ArrayList whenever you had an index higher than one you'd seen before, which may require reallocation internal to the ArrayList.

In short: there's no significant performance penalty for using an ArrayList if you do it in a reasonable way, but no particular benefit either.

Comment: Thanks I was oblivious to some things you have made clear

Answer (score 0):

> What is the time complexity of a HashMap implemented using dynamic array?

The short answer is: It depends on how you actually implement the `put` and `get` methods, and the rehashing.  However, assuming that you have gotten it right, then the complexity would be the same as with classic arrays.

Note that a typical hash table implementation *will not benefit* from using a dynamic array (aka a `List`).

- In between resizes, a hash table has an array whose size is fixed.  Entries are added and removed from buckets, but the number of buckets and their positions in the array do not change.  Since the code is not changing the array size, there is no benefit in using dynamic arrays in between the resizes.
- When the hash table resizes, it needs to create a new array (typically about twice the size of the current one).  Then it recompute the entry -> bucket mappings and redistributes the entries.  Note that a new array is required, since it is not feasible to redistribute the entries "in place".  Secondly, the size of the new array will be known (and fixed) when it is allocated.  So again there is no benefit here from using a dynamic array.

Add to this that for all primitive operations on an array, the equivalent operations for a dynamic array (i.e. `ArrayList`<sup>1</sup>) have a small performance overhead.  So there will be a small performance hit from using a dynamic array in a hash table implementation.

---

Finally, you need to be careful when talking about complexity of hash table implementations.  The **average** complexity of `HashMap.put` (and similar) is `O(1)` **amortized**.

- A single `put` operation may be `O(N)` if it triggers a resize.
- If the hash function is pathological, all operations can be `O(N)`.
- If you choose an inappropriate load factor, performance will suffer.
- If you implement an incorrect resizing policy then performance will suffer.

(Amortized means averaged over all similar operations on the table.  For example, N insertions with different keys into an empty table is `O(N)` ... or `O(1)` amortized per insertion.)

In short: the complexity of hash tables is ... complex.

---

<sup>1 - a `Vector` will be slightly worse than an `ArrayList`, but  `LinkedList` would actually make the complexity for `get` and `put` `O(N)` instead of `O(1)`.  I'll leave you to figure out the details.</sup>